# Reuse same POCO class for a nested output

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, poco

I have an .NET Core API that has to return the following output,

```
{
   "TotalValue":200,
   "Count":100,
   "TypeA":
   {
    "TotalValue":200,
   "Count":100   
   }
   "TypeB":
   {
    "TotalValue":200,
   "Count":100   
   }
}
```

I've tried the following to achieve this,

```
 public interface IValue
    {
        public int TotalValue { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public class Type : IValue
    {
        public int TotalValue { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test
    {
        public int TotalValue 
        {
            get 
            {
                return TypeA?.TotalValue ?? 0 + TypeB?.TotalValue ?? 0;
            }
        }
        public int Count 
        {
            get
            {
                return TypeA?.Count ?? 0 + TypeB?.Count ?? 0;
            }
        } 

        public Type TypeA { get; set; }
        public Type TypeB { get; set; }
    }
```

But the values get not added at all, I feel like there is a lot of duplication that could be avoided in this way even if I get it to work, Is there a more elegant solution to achieve this?

I have to set the values of TypeA and TypeB separately, the value of TypeA gets set but when I set the value to TypeB, the summation is not happening.

Comment: Well `TypeA` and `TypeB` are identical so you can use the same class for both properties.

Comment: yes I should have thought of that. Still the summing of the values is not happening. Also what happens when I have to set the values for TypeA and TypeB in separate operations?

Comment: you have to make sure you set TypeA and TypeB before you call the computed properties.

Comment: When I set the value for TypeA, the values are computed but its not happening the next time I set for TypeB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The summation does not seem to occur due to the precedence of the operator `??`. When you write this:

```
TypeA?.TotalValue ?? 0 + TypeB?.TotalValue ?? 0;
```

It may actually mean this:

```
(TypeA?.TotalValue) ?? (0 + TypeB?.TotalValue ?? 0);
```

So if you have `TypeA` not null, only its `TotalValue` returned. The value from `TypeB` is ignored no matter it's null or not. If you have `TypeA` null and `TypeB` not null. The returned value then is from `TypeB.TotalValue`.

In case you're not sure about the operator's precedence, you should explicitly use parentheses to group the expressions the way you want. It also helps make the expression clearer.

To fix it, just group the way you want (as I understand) like this:

```
public int TotalValue 
{
     get 
     {
         return (TypeA?.TotalValue ?? 0) + (TypeB?.TotalValue ?? 0);
     }
}
public int Count 
{
     get
     {
         return (TypeA?.Count ?? 0) + (TypeB?.Count ?? 0);
     }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks a lot for the clear explanation as well.